# Angular slider change change value dynamically

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a simple widget on angular slider. I use angular-slider library.
The core I idea is quite simple. I have a bar that has range between 0 to 1000. And two input fields.

The first field track the slider and displays the value of it e.g  100,50, 950 etc.

And the second field displays the value of slider, and multiplies that by 10.
For example the value on slider is 100 so the second field will display 1000.

Everything works fine except that the value on second field does not change dynamically.It changes only when I remove the previous value.

I use ng-change on my slider , however it does not work.

Maybe somebody has been working on angular slider and have done something similar.

Any help would be appreciated

```js
(function() {
  angular
    .module('rzSliderDemo', ['rzModule', 'ui.bootstrap'])
    .controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

  function MainCtrl() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.fisrtValue = 1000;
    vm.multiply = multiply;
    vm.sum = 0;

    function multiply() {
      vm.sum = vm.fisrtValue * 10;
    };

    multiply();
  }

})();
```

```html
<article>
  <h2>Simple slider</h2>
  <h2>Your Value is <i>{{vm.fisrtValue}}</i></h2>
  <input ng-model="vm.fisrtValue" ng-change="vm.multiply()" />
  <input ng-model="vm.sum" ng-change="vm.multiply()" />
  <h2>Value multiply 10 times <i>{{vm.sum}}</i></h2>
  <rzslider rz-slider-model="vm.fisrtValue" ng-change="vm.multiply()"></rzslider>
</article>
```

Comment: OK , after some time of research I did not find exactly what I was looking for , but at least it give correct result. What I did is simply add directive of ng-click on rzslider and passed my multiply function. its not 100% dynamic but it serves its purpose :)